# Why won't my flash messages show? CakePHP 2.2.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Why won't my flash messages show when I call the user controller? Here is my code:

AppController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers=array('Session');
    public $components = array('Session');
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Session->setFlash('This flash was set in AppController::beforeFilter.');
    }
}
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController {
        public function add() {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This flash was set in UsersController::add.');
        }
    }
```

My Layout...default.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>My website.</title>
    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

add.ctp

```
<p>This is the add view</p>
```

I am using the built in pages controller for my pages. Whenever I go to a page via the pages controller, it correctly displays the flash message with the correct view. But when I go to /users/add it shows the correct view but does not show the flash message. Anyone know why? I have been frustrated by this for days now. Thanks!

Comment: what browsers did you test it with? did you try to use $this->disableCache() in controllers beforeRender?

Comment: I copy/paste your code in a brand new cakephp 2.2.5 project and it work just fine. The homepage display the flash message "This flash was set in AppController::beforeFilter." and the /user/add page display this flash message "This flash was set in UsersController::add."

Comment: Mark what would that do? I tested with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: EmeraldCoder...I will redownload cakephp I guess? So frustrated.

Comment: Welp, I downloaded cake 2.3 and it works. Oh welllllll.

Comment: disableCache() is necessary for some browsers to not cache the site. You might notice strange session flash display message behavior if not used (at least we usually do).

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes in `usercontroller`.

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppControlle
{

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('This flash was set in UsersController::add.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Before filter is supposed to work in app controller if I don't declare it in any other controllers...good suggestion though. I tried it and it still doesn't work, but I downloaded cake 2.3 and pasted my previous code and it works.